# export PDF with custom GtkSourceView syntax highlighting via terminal

Tags: pdf, syntax-highlighting, gedit, gtksourceview

I created a custom syntax highlighting configuration for Gedit/GtkSourceView. It has worked well for my purposes, but now I am trying to find a way to export the highlighted text files as PDF via the Linux terminal.

I know that this is possible through the Gedit GUI function, but is this possible via the terminal?

I have come across the `enscript` GNU project, but this only seems to have pre-programmed syntax highlighting; I do not see a way to have it utilize GtkSourceView syntax highlighting/theme configurations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no way to print using GtkSourceView from the command line. With *enscript*, however, you can copy your own language definition file to `~/.enscript/`.

From the manual page:

> StatesPath: path
>
> Define the path for the states  program.   The  states  program will  lookup  its  state  definition files from this path.  The default value is `$HOME/.enscript:/usr/share/enscript/hl'.

Have a look at the `.st` files in `/usr/share/enscript/hl` for examples.